# Launching iOS application in background from another application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I am not aware much of APIs of iOS and its internals.

However, i want to run an application A in the background (not to launch application A in foreground) from another application B and do some tasks like downloading of content.

I would like to communicate between the apps using URL schemes.

In Android, it is possible to trigger an Android service in the background using implicit/explicit intents (URL schemes). I am looking for similar kind of APIs/components in iOS.

If not the whole application execution or any custom logic. Can I just execute NSURLSession from URL schemes which are used as a background content transfer job in iOS?

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: Such a thing is not possible on iOS. Launching an app for background execution without user knowledge is a security risk. What is your use case for this, if I may ask?

Comment: Use case is ..App B wants to trigger some action in App A . The action should happen in background and App A should not come in foreground.

Answer (score 1):

No and Yes

No, You cannot run another app from your app in background, but you can open it into foreground

Yes

If app A and B is developed by you, you can trigger a push notification from App A to B. B on receiving can execute your download code in background

Comment: Push notifications seems to be a good pointer...i will explore this and update in this thread